# Oracle WIDTH_BUCKET count in each Bucket

Tags: frequency

I have parent-child tables like customer to orders. Each order must belong to one and only one customer and a customer has zero, one or many orders.

How do I get a frequency distribution of COUNTS of orders. So the output would be:
count of customers with 0-100 orders
count of customers with 101-200 orders
count of customer with 201-300 orders.

I do NOT care about customer IDs, just the counts of orders.

I was trying to use the WIDTH_BUCKET function but it doesn't group and count the number of items in each bucket. Maybe there's another way, other than the WIDTH_BUCKET.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Hi Everyone,
  Thanks so much for your help in answering the question, and using the forum properly. I worked last night and the Grace of God - found a pretty simple solution - that give frequency distribution a boost. 
   This lets YOU (OK, your business partner) define the number of buckets and the bucket range.

Thanks Again!!
Alex

Answer (score 0):

I did some research last night on this issue and by the Grace of God found a solution that lets YOU (OK, your business partner) - define the bucket size, and counts for a distribution frequency count.

Here it is -- (sorry for the poor formatting on this website)
Thanks for All Your Help!!
Alex

```
with starter as(
select cust.customer_id, count(o.order_id) as row_count
from CUSTOMER cust  LEFT JOIN ORDER o
using (customer_id)
where cust.last_update_user = 'MDM_ETL' and
o.last_update_user = 'MDM_ETL' -- and
group by cust.customer_id
order by row_count desc)
select 5 , '2000 or more' as cnt_of_orders, count(starter.customer_id) as          
nmb_customers_with_this_cnt from starter where starter.row_count >= 2000
union 
select 4, '1500 - 1999' as cnt_of_orders, count(starter.customer_id) as    
nmb_customers_with_this_cnt from starter where starter.row_count between 1500 and 1999
union 
select 3, '1000 - 1499' as cnt_of_orders, count(starter.customer_id) as    
nmb_customers_with_this_cnt from starter where starter.row_count between 1000 and 1499
union 
select 2, '500 - 999' as cnt_of_orders, count(starter.customer_id) as   
nmb_customers_with_this_cnt from starter where starter.row_count between 500 and 999
union 
select 1, '0 - 499' as cnt_of_orders, count(starter.customer_id) as    
nmb_customers_with_this_cnt from starter where starter.row_count between 0 and 499
```